# Updating with a JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

how do i fix my query? I need to update my table to add inventory to the inventory table which is different from the order table

currently here is my query.

```
$qry = "UPDATE inventory 
        SET inventory.prod_quantity = inventory.prod_quantity + order_detail.quantity
        FROM inventory
        RIGHT JOIN order_detail on inventory.id=order_detail.orderid 
        WHERE inventory.id='{$_REQUEST['productid']}' ";
```

but it doesnt work. I dont know if i did it wrong or something. it wont add and i think my query format is wrong, im new with joins so an explanation would be nice.

productid is the same as id in inventory table.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it doesn't work"? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Comment: @Mureinik it doesnt add.

Comment: UPDATE inventory 
        
        RIGHT JOIN order_detail on inventory.id=order_detail.orderid 
SET inventory.prod_quantity = inventory.prod_quantity + order_detail.quantity
       
        WHERE inventory.id='{$_REQUEST['productid']}' ";

Comment: @PrasanthVJ it still didnt work.